# jquery autocomplete display custom result

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I use jQuery autocomplete and try to display custom results with thumbnails, titles, and links.

However, I have some difficulties making it work.

```
source: function(req, response){
    $.getJSON(search_ac.url+'?callback=?&action='+acs_action, req, function( data ) {
        response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
            jQuery.each( item, function( i, val ) {
                label = item.label;
                category = item.category;
                thumbnail = item.thumbnail;
                link = item.link;
                renderHtml = "<a class='urlpageautocomplete' href='" + link + "'><div class='image-autocomplete'><img class='normal' src='"+thumbnail+"'/></div>" + "<div class='title-autocomplete'>" + label + "</div><div class='category-autocomplete'>" + category + "</div></a>";
            })
            return $(renderHtml);
        }));
    });
},
```

With `return $(renderHtml)`, autocomplete menu appears (with the right number of item) but nothing is displayed inside it.

With `return renderHtml`, autocomplete menu appears and inside each item appears the right content but in text format. 
it returns text like this :

`"<a class='link' href='www.website.com'><div class='image-autocomplete'><img class='normal' src='www.website.com/img.png' /></div><div class='title-autocomplete'>my post title</div><div class='category-autocomplete'>blog</div></a>"`

How can I display rendered html from `renderHtml` var?

Comment: Can you please post the string that is returned when you use `return renderHtml`?

Comment: Can you show the response that comes back from the server?

Answer (score 0):

here the working script:

```
.data( 'ui-autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append(item.value)
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```