# Ajax search form django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, autocomplete

Trying to create a search form .Currently using ajax autocomplete function for this purpose.

```
  <div  class="ui-widget">
   <label for="search">Search for friends: </label>
   <input id="search">
 </div>



   $(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: "/accounts/ajax/search/",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui )
  });
});
```

Below is my view that processes my ajax request.

```
 def get_ajax_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('term', '')
    print(query)
    if request.is_ajax():
        qs1 = BasicUser.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=query)) 
        results = []
        for user in qs1:
            basic_user_json = {}
            basic_user_json['id'] = user.pk
            basic_user_json['label'] = user.first_name+" "+  user.last_name
            basic_user_json['value'] = user.first_name+" "+  user.last_name
            results.append(basic_user_json)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Appreciate your help with a couple of questions:

1. How can I redirect to a different page when selecting results.
2. How can I display a user profile picture next to every search result

Comment: Hi Ken, dont write multiple questions on a single post like this. Write a single, clear question, that can be answered with a single answer. If you have multiple questions, write multiple posts.

Comment: As @jonasfh stated you may want to atleast remove the question 3 because it is a going to to a lot to handle in here or even to ask it properly.

Comment: First time posting on stack overflow. Will try to improve my questions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How can I redirect to a different page when selecting results.
>      Try something like below example:

Here is a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/MieqYB6K7inzPVBiinDZ?p=preview

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: "/accounts/ajax/search/",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {

        window.open('http://example.com/'+ui.item.value, '_blank')
    }
  });
```

> 2. How can I display a user profile picture next to every search result Most importantly

You can follow

[jquery autocomplete display custom result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599257/jquery-autocomplete-display-custom-result)

> 3. is there a better way of retrieving data from the database and sending it to the ajax function, assuming it's going to be a high load website. Any ideas or insights would be appreciated.

This is very subjective. You will have to define "better".
I suggest use HTML image sources as per the SO question so that at least retrieving those images is asynchronous otherwise your server call will take long time to retrieve inline image data for each item.